# Как сделать глобальную переменную такой, чтобы не меняла своё значение при переходах по страницам

Tags: javascript, переменные

Имеется конструкция:

```
while (){
...
  if (){
  is = 1;
  }
}
```

Этот пример работает на нужной странице (там, где выполняется цикл и `is = 1` сохраняется), но после перехода на другую, `while` не выполняется (так и нужно) и, соответственно, `is` не присваевается `1`.

Как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения цикла на определенной странице значение `is` становилась равным `1` навсегда (на всех других страницах `is` тоже будет равен `1`)?

Скрипт - расширения для хрома.

P.S.: js учить только начал, поэтому, возможно, каких-то простых вещей не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вариантов может быть несколько:

1. Грузить значение переменной с куки;
2. Грузить значение переменной с локального хранилища;
3. Не переходить на другие страницы. Все страницы загружать через `ajax`.

Answer (score 1):

Данные между переходами можно сохранять в:

- sessionStorage и localStorage
- window.name
- куках
- и ещё нескольких менее популярных местах

Для определения перехода между страницами можно использовать события:

- load
- beforeunload
- unload

Выбираем нужный комплект, совмещяем в желаемом порядке и пользуемся.

Answer (score 1):

Я лишь представлю код:

```
function saveGlobalVar(name, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(name, value); // сохраняем в localStorage значение
}
function getGlobalVar(name) {
    return localStorage.getName(name); // получаем значение свойства localStorage
}
```

Теперь в вашем скрипте просто пишете:

```
while (...){
    if (...){
        saveGlobalVar('is', 1);
    }
}
```

А на другой странице уже просто получаем

```
var is = getGlobalVar('is');
```

**P.S**
Более того, есть даже события изменения localStorage, поэтому ваши значения могут передаваться между вкладками в режиме реального времени
[Заголовок: 'Responding to storage changes with the StorageEvent'](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)