# Как захватить и сохранить utm метку?

Tags: javascript

Например, человек переходит на сайт по ссылке:

```
http://site.com/page1/?utm_source=google&ut%C2%ADm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=your-campa%C2%ADign&utm_content=offer%20&network={network}&placement={pl%C2%ADacement}&position={adposition}&a%C2%ADdid={creative}&match={matchtype}&%C2%AD;utm_term=zapros
```

Задача распарсить метку и сохранить значение `utm_term=zapros`

Мои познания в javascript малы, но вот что у меня работает

```
var a = decodeURIComponent(location.search.substr(1)).split('&');
alert("Вы нашли нас по запросу" +  a[9]);
```

Куда теперь можно сохранить значение `a[9]`, чтобы, например, на странице  `http://site.com/page2/` была доступна эта переменная, которую потом можно отправить вместе с данными через форму заказа?

---

На страничке с utm меткой этот код работает,

```
if(location.search === " ") {
console.log(location.search);
} 
else {
var a = decodeURIComponent(location.search.substr(1)).split('&');
window.name = a[9]; 
console.log(window.name);
}
```

но если перейти на другую страницу и этот код отработает снова, то `window.name` станет `undefined`. То же самое происходит, если он отработает на 1 странице 2 раза. Не пойму почему.

Comment: Сохранение данных между разными страницами уже было: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425633/178988

Comment: Благодарочка за window.name )

Answer (score 1):

Варианты:

1. парсить GET параметры на сервере и запоминать значение `$_GET['utm_term']` (если php) в сессию. При записи принятой формы дополнять значением из сессии.
2. сохранить JavaScript'ом в куки. При сохранении формы дополнить значением из принятых кук.
3. средствами Google Analytics без доработки сайта ваша задача точно не решается?