# Выполнение скрипта при переходе с другой страницы

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такой функционал. С главной страницы сайта есть две ссылки на другую страницу (одну и ту же). Как сделать, что бы при переходе по одной ссылке выполнялось одно событие, а по второй ссылке другое (в данном случае присвоение разных классов диву)?

Интересует вариант без якорей ("#" в адресной строке - мешает работе фильтра расположенного на странице, а его ковырять очень уж сложно).

Comment: По-моему ваш cкрипт на js поломается при попытке открыть такую ссылку в новом окне

Answer (score 1):

- Можно отправлять post-запрос при клике на ссылку (скриптом или просто
  ссылки сделать типа `submit`), а сервер уже на основе переданного
  значения будет выдавать разный результат (только при обновлении
  страницы браузер будт спрашивать, отправить ли форму заново)
- Если вас устроит, то можно get-запрос отправлять, только в url будет 
  инфа (после ?, однако якоря # тут не нужны).
- Можно также при клике писать cookie javascript'ом и на основе него
  сервер будет работать.

Вообще самый простой и естественный вариант - get-запрос (просто ссылку изменить соответствующим образом), если не устраивает - смотрите по ситуации (однако стоит помнить - у пользователя могут быть отключены сookie и javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку [Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) для записи того по какой ссылке перешли.

Answer (score 0):

В обработчике клика по ссылке сохрани какую-либо информацию в sessionStorage (желательно) или в [одно из мест](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425633/178988), в которых данные сохранятся при переходе на другую страницу.

А на той странице проверь эти данные и выполни нужные действия.
Только не забудь потом эти данные стереть из хранилища.

PS: А вообще, сама идея такое делать - плохая.