# Сохранение значения при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы значение сохранялось при переходе на другую страницу?

Есть у меня `number.value` и нужно, чтобы ее значение сохранялось при переходе на другую страницу.

Смысл в том, что когда открывается страница, из нее мы берем `number.value` и сохраняем его где-то, а уже исходя их этого `value` делаем те или действия на другой странице.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `Coocie`.

Comment: @user191380 Используйте sessionStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходим механизм [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Например на первой странице сохраняем значение переменной:
`localStorage.setItem("someNumber", number.value);`
На последующих, это значение можно получить:
`localStorage.getItem("someNumber");`

Comment: Немного непонятно куда сюда вставлять number.value...

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("someNumber", number.value); // Сохраняем`       
`localStorage.getItem("someNumber"); // Получаем`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все получилось! Можете, пожалуйста, прислать какой-нибудь урок как правильно обращаться к этим данным теперь?

Comment: [Неплохая вводная статья](http://myrusakov.ru/html5-local-storage.html). Механизм Web Storage API очень легок для понимания. Удачи!

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Все работает кроме одного... На другую страницу не переносятся значение...

Comment: Откройте 2 вкладки данного примера: http://jsfiddle.net/6yjnxwow/1/. Затем необходимо добавить следующий код: `localStorage.setItem('key', 'newValue');` вне блока if в первой вкладке, нажать кнопку Run. Затем перейти во вторую вкладку, нажать на кнопку Run, значение уже будет не value, а newValue, т.е мы изменили значение для всего сайта.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, теперь данные сохраняются, но не работает почему-то indexOf..
Скрипт:

if(localStorage.getItem('someNumber') == undefined)
{
 localStorage.setItem('someNumber', 'opy.value');
    var val = localStorage.getItem('someNumber');
}

if (val.indexOf('тест1') +1)
{
    alert();
}

т.е. он сохраняет в localstorage value а value = тест1 и мне нужно сделать проверку, но не работает..

Вот если использовать просто без localStorage то работает, вот так работает:


if (opy.value.indexOf('не получаем ответы') +1)
{
    alert();
}

Comment: Рабочий пример: http://jsfiddle.net/fxmnevt0/

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Все работает как часики, а можно еще один вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте куки для хранения:

```
var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Данные между переходами можно сохранять в:

- sessionStorage и localStorage
- window.name
- куках
- и ещё нескольких менее популярных местах

Для определения перехода между страницами можно использовать события:

- load
- beforeunload
- unload

Выбираем нужный комплект, совмещяем в желаемом порядке и пользуемся.

---

[Как сделать глобальную переменную такой, чтобы не меняла своё значение при переходах по страницам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425621/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%91-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85)