# Какие есть способы вернутся на строку которая была активна до перезагрузки\рефреша страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня реализован  список раскрывающихся `div` элементов, нечто вроде т.н. аккордеона, в раскрывающейся панели у меня находятся поля -`input`. После того как я сделал запись в поле у меня происходит сохранение записи. И панели все сворачиваются. Как мне сделать так чтобы после сохранения записи:
Раскрывалась(курсор/фокус перемещался) на панель на которой происходило редактирование.
Ищу пока только общее понимание решения такой задачи.
Потому прошу направить в нужном направлении где/что почитать!

Ниже примерная разметка и скрипт создающий скрывающие панели.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="header" id="labelTile" data-id="Petersburg">02/02/2010 S. Petersburg</div>
   <div class="elem" data-id="Petersburg" style="display: none;">
     <div class="el"><input type="text" width="100" name="an_input0" id="an_input0" value="S.Petersburg"></div>
   </div>
  <div class="header" id="labelTile" data-id="Moscow">02/02/2010 S. Petersburg</div>
  <div class="elem" data-id="Moscow" style="display: none;">
     <div class="el"><input type="text" width="100" name="an_input0" id="an_input0" value="Moscow"></div>
   </div>
</div>

 <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $('div.elem').hide(); 
           $('div.header').click(function(){ 
             $(this).next().slideToggle();
         }); 
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать глобальную переменную такой, чтобы не меняла своё значение при переходах по страницам](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425621/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%91-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, разобрался с вопросом, привожу решение, критика приветствуется.) Я новенький нуб в этом деле.

Код слайдера:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   div = $('div.elem').hide(); 
         $('div.header').click(function(){ 
           var activeItem = $(this).next('div')
           div.not(activeItem).slideUp();
           $(this).next().slideToggle(600);

     }); 
 });
 </script>
```

Функция сохранения в локальном хранилище позиции активного слайдера, после рефреша страницы:

```
 <script>
 $('.header').on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   var id = this.id, //кликнутая панель
       val = e.target.value;
   console.log("id:", id, "val:", val)
   sessionStorage.setItem("idiv", id)
});
</script>
```

Функция имитации клика по панели, которая была активна до обновления страницы.

```
<script>

        var idStor = sessionStorage.getItem("idiv");
        $("#" + idStor).trigger('click');

</script>
```

Советы по оптимизации будут очень кстати!

Comment: а в чем смысл `var loaded = sessionStorage.getItem('loaded');`?

Comment: @Grundy Ну как, сессия началась, и скрипт проверяет была ли перезагружена страница, и если нет присваивает значение `true`... И пока я писал этот комментарий, я понял к чему ты это)